# Mortality Rates - can I add individual rates together?

Tags: statistics

I need to calculate the mortality rates per 100,000 for various age groups (Ex: age 0-19), however the data I am given is broken down into smaller age categories (Ex: ages 0-4, 5-9, 10-14, 15-19). Can I simply add the rates together for each sub-age group to get the total mortality rate for 0-19 years?

Answer (score 1):

No. Suppose, for example, that the rate for each age group is 1 in 100,000. Then the overall rate should of course be 1 in 100,000, not 4 in 100,000. In general the overall rate is an *average* of the individual rates where each individual rate is weighted by the population of its age group. So you would compute the overall rate as (rate of group 1 * population of group 1 + rate of group 2 * population of group 2 + ...) / total population of all groups.